# Grouping datetime objects in Python by month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dictionary that maps an ID to a datetime object and numeric score for that given ID. What I want to do is create a new dictionary where the key-value pair is the month and the average score for all the objects in that month. What would be the easiest way to go about constructing this dictionary? Thanks!

This is what the dictionary looks like...

```
{878947806442119168: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 25, 12, 7, 41), 0.5411], 
878946025662296064: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 25, 12, 0, 37), -0.522], 
878725385235701761: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 24, 21, 23, 52), 0.6588], 
878717095701336064: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 24, 20, 50, 56), -0.5992], 
878715504063643648: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 24, 20, 44, 36), 0.3724], 
878711517537083392: [datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 24, 20, 28, 46), -0.3595] ... 
}
```

and what I would like is something like 
{Month : average score for that month}

Comment: hope the link can help https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html
and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) first and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) or [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), last [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
d = df.groupby(df[0].dt.month)[1].mean().to_dict()
print (d)
{6: 0.015266666666666687}
```

Or:

```
d = df.groupby(df[0].dt.strftime('%b'))[1].mean().to_dict()
print (d)
{'Jun': 0.015266666666666687}
```

---

```
d = df.groupby(df[0].dt.strftime('%b-%Y'))[1].mean().to_dict()
print (d)
{'Jun-2017': 0.015266666666666687}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `pandas`, you can also use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
# initialize with list
new_dict = defaultdict(list)

# update each keys and values as list
for pairs in my_dict.values():
    new_dict[str(pairs[0].month)].append(pairs[1])

# getting average
final_dict = {key: sum(values)/len(values) for key, values in new_dict.items()}
```